# MongoDB copydatabase error code 18 authentication failed

Tags: mongodb

I have `MongoDB Server` and I am trying to migrate my data from one server to the other server, My host server `port 27017` is opened but when I am trying to use below command I getting below response.

```
> db.auth("example", "***********")
1
> db.copyDatabase('exampledb', 'exampledb', "15.128.223.33:27017", "username", "password");
 {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Authentication failed.",
    "code" : 18,
    "codeName" : "AuthenticationFailed"
}
```

Also when I am opening this url `15.128.223.33:27017` then I am getting in response `It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.`. So I think connection is successfully happening to host server.

Can anyone please tell me why this is happening.

Comment: Which mongo db version do you have on both source and destination server?

Comment: @RootHacker The host has `3.4.6` and the destination has `3.4.10`